# Recover broken glusterfs node

Tags: glusterfs

I moved brick to another folder using command:

`gluster volume replace-brick glusterReplica1 gfs62:/disk1/glusterReplica1 gfs62:/disk2/glusterReplica1 commit force`

I got error back:

`volume replace-brick: failed: Commit failed on localhost. Please check log file for details.`

Then I checked status:

```
gluster volume info all

Volume Name: glusterReplica1
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: 1b53d6ca-37ff-45bb-b7e8-d65c68d5d409
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: gfs40:/disk2/glusterReplica1
Brick2: gfs62:/disk2/glusterReplica1
Options Reconfigured:
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
performance.client-io-threads: off

Volume Name: volume1
Type: Distribute
Volume ID: 7394ec84-2c79-40e3-ad0a-9eb35e757e3e
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: gfs40:/disk1/glusterVolume1
Options Reconfigured:
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
```

where I can see that the brick was relocated, so I tried to heal the brick, which resulted in another error:

```
gluster volume heal glusterReplica1
Launching heal operation to perform index self heal on volume glusterReplica1 has been unsuccessful:
Glusterd Syncop Mgmt brick op 'Heal' failed. Please check glustershd log file for details.
```

So I tried to restart service, which failed to do so:

```
service glusterd start
Job for glusterd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status glusterd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@vm-backup-machine:/disk2# 
root@vm-backup-machine:/disk2# 
root@vm-backup-machine:/disk2# systemctl status glusterd.service
● glusterd.service - GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/glusterd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-11-20 13:15:55 CET; 12s ago
  Process: 20185 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/glusterd -p /var/run/glusterd.pid --log-level $LOG_LEVEL $GLUSTERD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20564 (code=exited, status=15)
    Tasks: 8
   Memory: 2.6G
      CPU: 3.877s
   CGroup: /system.slice/glusterd.service
           └─19686 /usr/sbin/glusterfs -s localhost --volfile-id gluster/glustershd -p /var/run/gluster/glustershd/glustershd.pid -l /var/log/glusterfs/glustershd.log -S 

Nov 20 13:15:51 vm-backup-machine systemd[1]: Starting GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server...
Nov 20 13:15:55 vm-backup-machine systemd[1]: glusterd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 20 13:15:55 vm-backup-machine systemd[1]: Failed to start GlusterFS, a clustered file-system server.
Nov 20 13:15:55 vm-backup-machine systemd[1]: glusterd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 20 13:15:55 vm-backup-machine systemd[1]: glusterd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I checked the log, as suggested:

```
[2019-11-20 13:20:31.490171] I [MSGID: 100030] [glusterfsd.c:2556:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterd: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterd version 3.13.2 (args: /usr/sbin/glusterd
-p /var/run/glusterd.pid --log-level INFO)
[2019-11-20 13:20:31.494367] I [MSGID: 106478] [glusterd.c:1423:init] 0-management: Maximum allowed open file descriptors set to 65536
[2019-11-20 13:20:31.494387] I [MSGID: 106479] [glusterd.c:1481:init] 0-management: Using /var/lib/glusterd as working directory
[2019-11-20 13:20:31.494396] I [MSGID: 106479] [glusterd.c:1486:init] 0-management: Using /var/run/gluster as pid file working directory
[2019-11-20 13:20:31.496714] W [MSGID: 103071] [rdma.c:4631:__gf_rdma_ctx_create] 0-rpc-transport/rdma: rdma_cm event channel creation failed [No such device]
[2019-11-20 13:20:31.496733] W [MSGID: 103055] [rdma.c:4940:init] 0-rdma.management: Failed to initialize IB Device
[2019-11-20 13:20:31.496741] W [rpc-transport.c:350:rpc_transport_load] 0-rpc-transport: 'rdma' initialization failed
[2019-11-20 13:20:31.496781] W [rpcsvc.c:1770:rpcsvc_create_listener] 0-rpc-service: cannot create listener, initing the transport failed
[2019-11-20 13:20:31.496792] E [MSGID: 106243] [glusterd.c:1769:init] 0-management: creation of 1 listeners failed, continuing with succeeded transport
[2019-11-20 13:20:32.883681] I [MSGID: 106513] [glusterd-store.c:2241:glusterd_restore_op_version] 0-glusterd: retrieved op-version: 31302
[2019-11-20 13:20:32.889138] E [MSGID: 101032] [store.c:441:gf_store_handle_retrieve] 0-: Path corresponding to /var/lib/glusterd/vols/glusterReplica1/bricks/gfs62:-disk1
-glusterReplica1. [No such file or directory]
[2019-11-20 13:20:32.889167] E [MSGID: 106201] [glusterd-store.c:3365:glusterd_store_retrieve_volumes] 0-management: Unable to restore volume: glusterReplica1
[2019-11-20 13:20:32.889196] E [MSGID: 101019] [xlator.c:503:xlator_init] 0-management: Initialization of volume 'management' failed, review your volfile again
[2019-11-20 13:20:32.889208] E [MSGID: 101066] [graph.c:327:glusterfs_graph_init] 0-management: initializing translator failed
[2019-11-20 13:20:32.889217] E [MSGID: 101176] [graph.c:698:glusterfs_graph_activate] 0-graph: init failed
[2019-11-20 13:20:32.889665] W [glusterfsd.c:1393:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterd(glusterfs_volumes_init+0xe5) [0x56523aabb7f5] -->/usr/sbin/glusterd(glusterfs_p
rocess_volfp+0x16b) [0x56523aabb6bb] -->/usr/sbin/glusterd(cleanup_and_exit+0x54) [0x56523aabac84] ) 0-: received signum (-1), shutting down
```

Obviously the move command failed to update the config files correctly. Now I have no much ideas what to do, except start over. The node which is down was my master. My production is still operational, but I'm confident, that clients will not survive reboots, since mount from master must fail now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

https://superuser.com/questions/1215238/how-do-i-remove-a-replicated-glusterfs-peer

I purged gluster from broken node using apt, then I reinstalled it. The service started.

Then on working node I removed brick and then peer.

Finally I added new peer and brick following this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-new-brick-to-existing-glusterfs-replicated-volume/

Last think I triggered heal `gluster volume heal glusterReplica1` which started replicating data to new node.